# local variable in taglib not created

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, taglib

I would like to modify one of the plugins in my Grails project to add something in a TagLib class.

The plugin is pdf version 0.6 and I would like to add a variable that stores a path.

The TagLib is originally as follows:

```
def pdfLink = { attrs, body ->
    //String template = attrs['template']
    String pdfController = attrs['pdfController']
    String pdfAction = attrs['pdfAction']
    String pdfId = attrs['pdfId']
    //String pdfParams = attrs['pdfParams']
    String url = attrs['url']
    String filename = attrs['filename']
    ....
}
```

I've added the following:

```
String pdfPathToSave = attrs['pdfPathToSave']
```

Where `pdfPathToSave` is defined in gsp as follows:

```
<g:pdfLink class="pdf" .... pdfPathToSave="${path}"...></g:pdfLink>
```

I've put a breakpoint into the taglib and I see that, in `attrs['pdfPathToSave']` there is correctly stored the path, but the variable `pdfPathToSave` is not correctly created.

How can I create a new local variable into TagLib class?

Comment: What do you mean when you say variable pdfPathToSave is not properly created

Comment: It means that, looking at the variable via "watching" tab in Idea IDE, using a breakpoint after the instruction above, I see "Cannot find local variable pdfPathToSave"

Comment: if you have declared the variable pdfPathTosave in tag lib, it should work just fine even if debugger say can not find variable. try to print the value eg. println "### ${pdfPathTosave}" and see if that is printed

Comment: in controller, after clicking on button that creates the pdf, into params there is not pdfPathToSave...I see a missingPropertyException

Comment: How / where are you editing the plugin's tag lib source?

Comment: better re-implement this source in your project. For example: put this taglib to the simple package in your project, that you can normally deploy it everywhere.

Comment: I'm editing directly the plugin, in its source code that I've inside my project. In Intellij Idea IDE I've a Plugins section where I can see and edit plugin source code. @Koloritnij how can I re-implement only this taglib in source to be used in plugin?

Comment: just copy this file and paste it to your projects folder taglib with simple packages

Comment: yes...i've copied files and everything works...if you write an answer I will accept it!